# MS access add item to combo box if non in list

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have an access form, i want to know how to add item in combo box if there is not in there.
my combo box is in value mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change the rowsource permanently without changing the form to design mode and adding the new value. It is possible to do this with code, but it is not a good idea when people are working. The easiest thing is to create a small table and add the values to that. New values will then be saved when you close the form.

Allen Browne has a description of how to do this : http://allenbrowne.com/ser-27.html

This is one of the ideas he shows:

```
Private Sub CategoryID_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    Dim strTmp As String

    'Get confirmation that this is not just a spelling error.
    strTmp = "Add '" & NewData & "' as a new product category?"
    If MsgBox(strTmp, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Not in list") = vbYes Then

        'Append the NewData as a record in the Categories table.
        strTmp = "INSERT INTO Categories ( CategoryName ) " & _
            "SELECT """ & NewData & """ AS CategoryName;"
        DBEngine(0)(0).Execute strTmp, dbFailOnError

        'Notify Access about the new record, so it requeries the combo.
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the property `limit to list` to true.

Then add some code in the On Not In List event that potentially adds the value to the combo box. [Here is a tutorial.](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut20.htm) Or you can view the other answer.

Please note that it is usually better to utilize a table that stores the values for your combo box. With a value list, unless you disable the shortcut menus a user can right click on the combo box select `Edit List Items...` and modify the list even if it is set to limit to list... which effectively defeats any limitation you are trying to place on the field.