# MS Access 2010, Data to 2 tables from 1 form with duplicate check before entry on form 2

Tags: forms, ms-access, search

I've done some small projects in Access before, and I'm having an issue wrapping my head around something a bit more complicated.

I'm setting up a database to track boats.  (I'll spare you the story of why.)  I have two main tables: Table A is all of the information on the individual boats, table B is all of the owner's information.  For ease of use on the users, I need to create a form that mimics the hand written form people filled out that the user needs to enter into the database.

This seems simple enough, and if I was using a simple DB as I have in the past, I wouldn't be here looking for help.  BUT, since the form has the boat and owner information, I need the form to always enter the boat information into Table A, but when the owner information is entered, I need to check Table B to see if the person is already in the table, and if they're not, add the owner information to Table B, and associate the two records, OR if the check shows the owner information is already in Table B, I need it to associate the new boat information being put into the form, and thus being put into table A with the owner information that is already in table B so I don't wind up with duplicate data.

This probably sounds more complicated when I explain it than it actually is, but since I'm stuck with the handwritten form that's already created, I'm trying to make this as simple as I can on the end user.  Basically, since one person can own more than one boat, I need it to check before adding new user info, and get the boat info to either associate with the new owner entry, or the one that already exists if that's the case.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [MS access add item to combo box if non in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487979/ms-access-add-item-to-combo-box-if-non-in-list)?

Answer (score 0):

Make the entry form **unbound**.

Check the owner data against your existing table.

Then if the owner does not yet exist add both an owner record and a boat record, otherwise just add the boat record with the existing owner ID.